# Backing up RavenDB - is it safe to backup data directory without VSS?

Tags: database-backup, vss, ravendb

The documentation for RavenDB basically indicates there are several ways of backing up your RavenDB database:

- Using the supplied Raven.Backup.exe tool
- Initiating an export from the "studio" web interface
- Using the client API
- Using VSS (Volume-Shadow-copy-Services) to copy the RavenDB data directory
- Initiating an export (not really a true backup) using the "Smuggler" tool or via the studio web interface.

I believe the backups at my organisation are being done "naively" (i.e. directly copying the RavenDB data directory, *without* involving VSS).

Questions:

- Are there risks associated with directly copying the RavenDB data directory (not using VSS)? Instinctively, it seems like a bad idea (TM) to me.
- If we do want to start using VSS, how should we go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Hibernating Rhinos (RavenDB vendor) who responded:

> We require VSS for proper backup if you are using an external tool.
>   To be frank, it is usually better to use the internal backup tooling of RavenDB

So "naively" copying the RavenDB data directory is a no-no.